# encapsulating a date in filename

Tags: bash, regular-expression, rename

I have a ton of video files that contain a date as such; "filename 1981.mkv", basically a "space + date + .", I would like to enclose the date in parenthesis, ie - "filename (1981).mkv".

- Some files have the year in the filename, some do not.
- Some files have other numbers in the filename.
- Some of the filenames have already been changed (manually).

I am not bash-savvy enough to figure this out on my own, help is appreciated!

Comment: Given your example, I assume a "date" can **only** ever look like a 4-digit year?

Comment: Can the filenames contain dates, 4 digit numbers or other spaces in their _names_?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  The date is nothing but a 4-digit year.

The filenames can contain other spaces  or numbers, but only this one has a preceding space and a following period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the files that you'd like to rename matches the pattern `*' '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].mkv`:

```bsh
for name in *' '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].mkv; do
    suffix=${name##* }        # remove all up to the last space of $name
    suffix=${suffix%.mkv}     # remove .mkv from end of $suffix
    suffix="($suffix).mkv"    # add parentheses and .mkv

    # Remove old suffix from $name by truncating
    # the name at the last space and then adding
    # the new suffix after a space, then rename
    # the original file.
    newname="${name% *} $suffix"

    printf '"%s" --> "%s"\n' "$name" "$newname"
    mv -- "$name" "$newname"
done
```

Testing:

```
$ ls -1
filename 1980.mkv
filename 1981.mkv
filename 1982.mkv
filename 1983.mkv
filename 1984.mkv
filename 1985.mkv
script
```

```
$ sh script
"filename 1980.mkv" --> "filename (1980).mkv"
"filename 1981.mkv" --> "filename (1981).mkv"
"filename 1982.mkv" --> "filename (1982).mkv"
"filename 1983.mkv" --> "filename (1983).mkv"
"filename 1984.mkv" --> "filename (1984).mkv"
"filename 1985.mkv" --> "filename (1985).mkv"
```

The script does not handle name collisions.

---

Using the Perl implementation of the `rename` command (sometimes called `prename`):

```bsh
rename -v 's/(\d{4})\.mkv$/($1).mkv/' *.mkv
```

Note that if you have *other* files that matches `*.mkv`, this command would not rename them, as the PCRE `(\d{4})\.mkv$` does not match.

Testing:

```
$ rename -v 's/(\d{4})\.mkv$/($1).mkv/' *.mkv
filename 1980.mkv renamed as filename (1980).mkv
filename 1981.mkv renamed as filename (1981).mkv
filename 1982.mkv renamed as filename (1982).mkv
filename 1983.mkv renamed as filename (1983).mkv
filename 1984.mkv renamed as filename (1984).mkv
filename 1985.mkv renamed as filename (1985).mkv
```

Running again won't rename any files:

```
$ rename -v 's/(\d{4})\.mkv$/($1).mkv/' *.mkv
```

(no output)

Comment: This works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(**/)(* )(<1900-2021>)(.mkv)' '$1$2($3)$4'
```

remove `-n` (dry-run) if happy.

Note that the `<1900-2021>` matches decimal numbers in that range regardless of how many digits they're made of. If you'd rather it not match on `00002000` for instance (and there's a chance such sequence of digits be found in the file name), you can restrict it to only those made of four characters by changing the `(<1900-2021>)` to `(<1900-2021>~^????)`. That is, using the `~` *except* operator and the `^` *not* one followed by `????` to match 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pattern is always `<space>dddd.mkv` (d = digit) you can do this:

Example of file names

```
a 1986 filename 1981.mkv
filename 1981.mkv
```

The code:

```bsh
for i in *.mkv; do
  echo "${i% [0-9.]*} (${i: -8:4}).mkv"
  # the below command will change the names
  # try with `echo` to check discrepancies in the file names
  # mv -- "$i" "${i% [0-9.]*} (${i: -8:4}).mkv"
done

a 1986 filename (1981).mkv
filename (1981).mkv
```

Comment: The `mv` command renames the files, the `echo` command will show you how the names would be changed. In the code above, `mv` is commented with `#`, if you delete the character, the rename will be executed.

Comment: This mostly works, but it messes up filenames that have already been changed.
 It also messes up any files that don't contain a year

Comment: @user88710 I thought all the files where the same. You should maybe [edit] the question clarifying what kind of names are there.